How can i calculate Total density of state from DOSCAR file
I am trying to draw a DOS-energy graph in python and excel.
And I know that the sum of orbitals does not match the overall DOS.
For example, I drew a Si DOS graph.
I added the s and d orbitals of Si. Then I compared it with the reference.
The s, d orbitals are correct, but the Total DOS is lower than the reference. The shape is good, but the Total  DOS is low.
And I know that all the Total DOS of other materials have the same problem.
How can I calculate the Total DOS?

I suggest lowering smearing parameter and checking number of total electrons.
